# Regarding "Assumptions" under "Integrate"

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

Sir,

I tried to integrate the following in mathematica

```
 Integrate[(
 E^((I k (2 l^2 - 2 y y' + (y')^2))/(
  2 l)) (I a E^((I a^2 k)/(8 l)) Sqrt[k l] + 
    2 Sqrt[\[Pi]] (FresnelC[(a Sqrt[k/l])/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])] + 
       I FresnelS[(a Sqrt[k/l])/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])]) (l (-I + k l) + 
       k (2 y - y') y')))/(k l)^(
 3/2), {y', -(b/2)*Sin[\[Omega]'*t'], (b/2)*Sin[\[Omega]'*t']}, 
 Assumptions -> 
  a > 0 && Element[a, Reals] && t' > 0 && b > 0 && Element[b, Reals] &&
    k > 0 && l > 0 && \[Omega]' > 0 && Element[y, Reals] && 
   Element[Sin[\[Omega]'*t'], Reals]]
```

and it does not show any result but if I remove the assumptions of a,b are the Reals, it gives answer. I can't understand what is going on or is there any mistake in input language?

Kindly, help me...Thanking you...

Comment: To me (version 12.1) it gives a solution in either case. Anyway I think if you put a>0 it is already telling mathematica it is real.

Comment: Thanks, Sir ... I shall remove the "a,b are real" but y (real) could be +ve or -ve. So, then is it required to be mentioned ?

Comment: Yes, leave Element[y, Reals]

Comment: Thanks sir.. for your kind help..

Comment: Since `\[Omega]' > 0 && t' > 0` I think you can drop `Element[Sin[\[Omega]'*t'], Reals]` Your use of ' after variable names really worries me. Does the documentation say that this is acceptable?

Comment: @Bill `Symbol["x\[Prime]"]` is a valid symbol, but `Symbol["x'"]` is not, and `SymbolName[x']` will not work either. You can also enter ' as `\[RawQuote]`. It makes no sense to me that it works because it neither behaves like a subscript, nor a diacritical mark.

Comment: I think it's a very bad idea, because `Head[First[Hold[x']]]` is `Derivative[1]`

Comment: Okay, Sir, as you suggest,  i shall avoid writing primed symbol in the syntax for further use..